# How to show the labels in satellite view in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

My map is displaying fine. BUT no lables are shown on it. I can show the lables when I check the **satellite => label**.

How I can check the **satellite => label** by default (through code). Now by default no labels are shown.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In your MapOptions object that you use to create the map, use `MapTypeId.HYBRID`, like this:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
```

Comment: I had to add `labels:true` as in 

`var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
  labels:true
};`

Comment: This worked for me. But is this in the documentation anywhere? I searched the official API documentation extensively before coming to this answer here. It's certainly not an intuitive solution to me because the on-map terminology doesn't use the word "hybrid" anywhere, only "labels" and "satellite".

Answer (score 15):

I don't know about an option to explicitly show the labels in the SATELLITE view.
The "styles" property was supposed to do this, but I had no lucky when tried this with the code below:

```
styles:[
    {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "on" }
        ]
    }
]
```

I ended up using the HYBRID map type, instead of using the SATELLITE one, and hiding the default user interface to turn off the visibility of the change map type menu, and hided the "road" element:

```
mapOptions: {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
styles: [
        {
        featureType: "road",
        stylers: [
                 {visibility: "off"}
             ]
        }
    ]
```