# Is there a way to enable labels by default on satellite view in Google Maps JS API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I've been experimenting with the Google Maps JS API in an React application. And I've got this satellite map with a marker, but the labels don't show up by default, and couldn't find the documentation on this issue.

Is there any way to enable this by default?

[image: Gif of desired default result]

Code:

```
const GoogleMap = ({
      coords,
      markerTitle = "Marker",
      zoom = 15,
      mapType = "satellite",
      className = "",

    }) => {
    const mapRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (coords) {
            const loader = new Loader({
                apiKey: API_KEY,
                version: "weekly",
            });
            let map;
            if (mapRef.current) {
                const { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } = coords;
                loader.load().then(() => {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, {
                        center: { lat, lng },
                        zoom,
                        mapTypeId: mapType,
                    });
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: { lat, lng },
                        map,
                        markerTitle,
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [coords]);
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408038/how-to-show-the-labels-in-satellite-view-in-google-maps might help.

Comment: Thanks everybody. It's resolved, didn't see that post when I searched on the issue :)

Comment: You can try searching on google itself like "How to enable labels by default on satellite view in Google Maps JS" then adding "Stack Overflow at the end". That's what I tried. Might help on your future searches. Glad I was able to help.